# Joining two colums to one colum in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been searching and still feel lost.

My sql DB is like this
bf_putnr -> colums:  PUTNR_ID|PUTNR
Data: 
PUTNR_ID  PUTNR
1         put_1
2         put_2
3         put_12
4         put_28
5         put_34

bf_rioo -> colums: RIOO_ID|PUTA|PUTB
RIOO_ID   PUTA   PUTB
1         put_1  put_2
2         put_1  put_28
3         put_12 put_1


PUTA and PUTB are the same as PUTNR in the table bf_putnr

in codeigniter i'd like to get the PUTNR_ID when getting all the bf_rioo data

This is what i came up with,

```
                $this->db->from('bf_rioo');

                $this->db->join('bf_putnr AS A', 'bf_rioo.PUTA = A.putnr');
                $this->db->join('bf_putnr AS B', 'bf_rioo.PUTB = B.putnr');
```

but it only returns the second join.
I think the second join is overwriting the data from the first one.
I get all colums from bf_rioo and all columns from bf_putnr but only joined on the last join statement.....?

How do i get the join on putnr to return the data for PUTA and PUTB ??

Comment: If column names are the same you may want to give them an alias before joining them. Do a `select('table_name.column_name as alias')`.

Comment: This produces the PUTA and PUTB data from bf_rioo  and i would also like to get the PUTNR_ID from the table bf_putnr

Comment: You need to tell it it's a left join ``join(table, condition, 'left');`` so you can get all the results when anything matches... currently you're only getting a match when both joins returns results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both join conditions in the same join statements.

```
$this->db->from('bf_rioo');
$this->db->join('bf_putnr AS A', 'bf_rioo.PUTA = A.putnr AND bf_rioo.PUTB = A.putnr);
```

Comment: returns an empty result, i think this makes the join wrong

Comment: Now i get it, the array is populated two time for every bf_rioo record!!

Comment: I need to do an array_search on the bf_rioo.PUTA and PUTNR to get the ID :)